# How do I import a class directly from a Python package?

Tags: python, module, package

I'm trying to make a python package where I can import a class directly into another project and use it.  Here is my file directory setup.

```
proj1
  proj1
    __init__.py
    proj1.py
  setup.py
proj2
  file.py
```

Where `__init__.py` is

```
from .proj1 import Proj1
```

and `setup.py` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(name='proj1',
      version='1.0',
      description='',
      author='',
      author_email='',
      url='',
      packages=find_packages(),
     )
```

and file.py contains

```
from proj1 import Proj1

class File(Proj1):
   ...
```

When I execute file.py, I get the error `cannot import name 'Proj1'`. I can import it if I have `from proj1.proj1 import Proj1`, but that's messy.

How can I import the class directly from the package?

Comment: `from proj1.proj1 import Proj1` is the way. It's "messy" only insofar as your folder-structure is "messy". You could always mess with the PYTHONPATH environment variable to add `proj1/proj1/` to the path.

Comment: Reddit's praw libary allows you to `import praw` and use praw.Reddit even though the Reddit class is in praw/praw/reddit.py. How can I emulate that? https://github.com/praw-dev/praw

Comment: read `praw.__init__`, you `from .reddit import Reddit` in `__init__`

Comment: I think I'm doing that in my `proj1.__init__`

Comment: yes, because you have *two `praw`* directories.

Comment: I still don't see what you're saying. I'm doing what they're doing in the __init__ file, but I can't use my class directly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant because you have *two `proj1` directories* . Note there is only one `praw` directory.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I renamed the subdir to proj and can now do `from proj import Proj1` successfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add the path of proj1 to your sys.path.  check out sys.path.insert.  E.g:

```
sys.path.insert(0, myPath)
```